# How to update prop value from child - React

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I'm new and trying to do something but can't THINK of a way (that works) to do so.
I have the following situation:

- Array with 5 cells that can hold one char, I am sending each cell as a prop to an Input tag, in my custom Input react component I want to update that cell to hold a key, but can't do so.

My code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Input from './Input'
const makeWords = require('make-words')

function Body() {

    const [word, setWord] = useState(makeWords.getWordByLength(5)) //create new word 
    const [guess, setGuess] = useState('') //saves guess from user
    let information = ['','','','',''] //array with 5 cells

    useEffect(() => { //when information array gets updated, set the guess to the new array value (toString)
        setGuess(information.join(''))
    }, [information])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className='secret-word'>{word}</h1>
            <Input className='letter-guess' info={information[0]}/>
            <Input className='letter-guess' info={information[1]}/>
            <Input className='letter-guess' info={information[2]}/>
            <Input className='letter-guess' info={information[3]}/>
            <Input className='letter-guess' info={information[4]}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Body
```

and

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function Input({ className, info }) {
    let [character, setCharacter] = useState('')//hold the character

    function onChangeEvent(event) { // handles key input to save character
        event.target.value = event.target.value.slice(-1)
        setCharacter(event.target.value)
    }

    return (
            <input type="text" className={className} onChange={onChangeEvent}/>// input tag
    )
}

export default Input
```

I would really appreciate any help especially one with explanation, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You are storing the state of the `word` in both the `Input` and `Body` components. It is generally not good practice to store the same state in two separate places. Try something like this instead:

```
function Body() {
    const [word, setWord] = useState(makeWords.getWordByLength(5))
    const [guess, setGuess] = useState('')
    const [information, setInformation] = useState(['','','','',''])

    useEffect(() => {
        setGuess(information.join(''))
    }, [information])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className='secret-word'>{word}</h1>
            <Input className='letter-guess' handleChange={setInformation} info={information} index={1} />
            <Input className='letter-guess' handleChange={setInformation} info={information} index={2} />
            <Input className='letter-guess' handleChange={setInformation} info={information} index={3} />
            <Input className='letter-guess' handleChange={setInformation} info={information} index={4} />
            <Input className='letter-guess' handleChange={setInformation} info={information} index={5} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then the `Input` component would look like this:

```
function Input({ className, handleChange, info, index }) {

    function updateInformation(e) {
        handleChange(() => {
            const newInfo = info;
            newInfo[index] = e.target.value;
            return newInfo;
            });
        }

        return (
            <input type="text" className={className} onChange={
            (e) => updateInformation(e)}/>
        )
    }
```

This code is probably too long but I think it gets the idea across. Pass the current state of `information` and the `setInformation` function as props to the `Input`. Then when any input changes, use the index to update the value and pass it to the `setInformation` function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understood your problem, but I think you want to be able to modify the prop info that you receive from your parent.

In that case the simplest way to do that is to have a state with the value and the setter in the parent, and pass to the child both the value and the setter.
The children now gets the value as a prop and also the function to modify that value when it wants.

Comment: Well you did manage to understand (sorry about that XD), Is there a way to send an array and update only one cell at a time for each Input?

Comment: No worries, glad that helped.
Yes, there are several ways to do that.

For instance, consider you have a state `[array, setArray] = useState([]);` inside your parent.

You can pass for the <index> Input as prop : `value={array[index]}` and an updateValue function that calls setArray to change the value with the correct index

Comment: sorry for alerting again, but I still fail to make it, I don't understand how to change the array according to the index (change on the correct index only)

Comment: I think that JBrown answered your question with the updateInformation? :)